# How to set background color to Onsen UI page

Tags: html, css, user-interface, styles, onsen-ui

I want to set background color of onsen ui page to blue or some color. I've tried updating the  style in onsen-page, but it seems not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

*html*

```
  <ons-page class="red">

    <h1>Page 1</h1>

  </ons-page>
```

*css*

```
 .red {
    background-color: red;
 }
```

Here is the plunker.
http://plnkr.co/edit/jWTrYz?p=preview

Comment: but when i put ons-page inside ons-navigator, it did't work.!

Comment: background will be changed back to its default when i added some of the onsen elements

Comment: i see the only way to set the background color of the page is to override unsen css file, in the .page

Answer (score 0):

For v2, let me quote @frandiox who provided this info on Gitter:

> provide a `<div class="background"></div>` element in your `v-ons-page` and that will be used as the background. You can style it as you want. More info here: https://onsen.io/v2/guide/compilation.html#page-compilation

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Javascript:

```
document.addEventListener("init",function(event){
  if(event.target.id == "trn")
    {
      $("#trn .page__background").css("background","#ffffff");
    }
});
```

onsen tag:

```
<ons-page id="trn">
</ons-page>
```

Comment: Maybe you could explain why this would work? It might make your answer more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation for the above answer from  malu ugo

**ons-page will compile in the following way:**
 *It adds .page, div.page__background and div.page__content automatically*

```
<ons-page class="page">
  <ons-toolbar></ons-toolbar>
  <div class="page__background"></div>
  <div class="page__content">
    Some content here
    <ons-input></ons-input>
    <div>More content</div>
  </div>
  <ons-fab></ons-fab>
</ons-page>
```

using javascript to change the background

**Javascript:**

```
document.addEventListener("init",function(event){
  if(event.target.id == "trn")
    {
      $("#trn .page__background").css("background","#ffffff");
    }
});
```

**onsen tag:**

```
<ons-page id="trn">
</ons-page>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ons-template id="tab1.html">
    <ons-page id="first-page" >
        <div class="background"></div>
            <p style="text-align: center;">
                My Text
            </p>    
     <style>
       .background{
             background-color: black;
                 }
    </style>
  </ons-page> 
</ons-template>
```

Adding a div of class background should help to style the background of the page